# A value of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool Function

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg9RY.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwIpC.png)

flutter  http.get has this problem CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED,

```
Then I added this code, and this problem occurred again "class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
   @override
   HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
     return super.createHttpClient(context)
       ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=>true;
   }
}"
```

A value of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)?'